# Turtlebot3 Bringup Issue

Tags: linux, ros

while using the command " roslaunch turtlebot3_bringup turtlebot3_robot.launch" for the turtlebot3. I am getting the following error:

RLException: Unable to contact my own server at [http://IP_ADDRESS_OF_RASPBERRY_PI:40449/].
This usually means that the network is not configured properly.

A common cause is that the machine cannot connect to itself.  Please check
for errors by running:

```
ping ip_address_of_raspberry_pi
```

For more tips, please see

```
http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/NetworkSetup
```

The traceback for the exception was written to the log file

I checked ping command and it is connected to TB3

Comment: This isn't a question...

Comment: What's the content of the .launch file?